# C++ , reading & writing to the same file after processing

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I am looking for a clean c++ solution to read and write to the same file after processing the string read from ifstream. For example this is what I have in mind

```
std::ofstream ofs("test.txt", std::ios_base::app);
std::ifstream ifs("test.txt");
std::string inputLine;
bool skipLine = false;

if (ofs)
{
    while (getline(ifs, inputLine))
    {
        skipLine = processLine(inputLine);

        if (!skipLine)
            ofs << inputLine << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work. I intend to read lines and decide in "processLine()" function weather I want to write the line back or skip it. The resulting output content will almost be the contents of the input line minus some line I want to purge

Comment: Are all lines the same length?  If not, you'll have to read the whole file before any writing is done. :(  Actually no, even if they're the same length, you can't "purge" like that.  Use a seperate output file.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use: `std::fstream IOFile( "Example.txt", std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::app );`? Within the function: processLine, what would cause it to return true/false? Just wondering.

Comment: Would it be okay to read the whole file to stringstream, modify it and write back?

Comment: @CLearner: That would append the output to the exsting input.  He wants to erase lines from an existing file.

Comment: @stardust_: Writing to a different file, then renaming is easier and uses less memory.

Comment: @Eternal Learner I think you should consider Mooing Duck's advice.

Comment: @MooingDuck yep I see from the next comment. I thought he was trying to append to it.

Comment: Why exactly would you wanna do that then? Why not just output to another file if you are not appending??

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option is to simply create a temporary file, which should be your output file. To explain why you should, please read the comments below your question.

And here is a good and clean example, which works fine:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/stat.h>

/*
 * @ FUNCTION: GenerateStr
 * @ PARAMETER(s):
 *      [1st - in] const size_t in_Length = This parameter
 *      take in a size_t, which should be the length of the
 *      generated std::string.
 * @ RETURN VALUE(s):
 *      This function should return the generated
 *      std::string, which was randomized during
 *      the generating process within this function.
 */
std::string GenerateStr( const size_t in_Length ) {
    const std::string Elements =
        "AaBcCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz1234567890$-_";
    std::string FileName = "";

    for( size_t Index = 0; Index != in_Length; ++ Index ) {
        //# Add random characters from Elements.
        FileName += Elements[ rand() % Elements.size() ];
    }

    return FileName;
};

/*
 * @ FUNCTION: FileExists
 * @ PARAMETER(s):
 *      [1st - in] const std::string &in_File = This parameter
 *      takes in a std::string, which should be the
 *      name of the file that will be searched for.
 * @ RETURN VALUE(s):
 *       false = The file does not exists.
 *       true = The file does exists.
 */
bool FileExists( const std::string &in_FileName ) {
    struct stat Buffer;
    return ( stat( in_FileName.c_str(), &Buffer ) != -1 );
};

/*
 * @ FUNCTION: GenerateTempFileName
 * @ PARAMETER(s):
 *      [1st - in] const size_t in_Length = This parameter
 *      takes in a constant size_t value, which should be
 *      length of temporary file name (a.k.a the returned
 *      value).
 * @ RETURN VALUE(s):
 *      This function will return a std::string, which
 *      should be a unique name for the temporary file.
 */
std::string GenerateTempFileName( const size_t in_Length ) {
    std::string TempFileName = "";
    while( FileExists( TempFileName = GenerateStr( in_Length ) + ".tmp" ) );
    return TempFileName;
};

/*
 * @ FUNCTION: OldFileToTempFile
 * @ PARAMETER(s):
 *      [1st - in] const std::string &in_OldFileName = The
 *      name of the old file.
 *      [2nd - in] const std::string &in_TempFileName = The
 *      name of the temporary file.
 * @ RETURN VALUE(s):
 *      1 = An error has occured when attempting to rename the
 *      the old file to a temporary name.
 *      -1 = An error has occured when attempting to rename the
 *      temporary file to the original name of the old file,
 *      which is in_OldFileName.
 *      -2 = This is only a warning, although this function
 *      successfully renamed the temporary file to the original
 *      name of the old file, it failed to delete the old file.
 *      0 = Successfully renamed the temporary file to
 *      in_OldFileName and deleted the old file.
 */
short OldFileToTempFile( const std::string &in_OldFileName,
                         const std::string &in_TempFileName )
{
    //# Generate a temporary name for the old file.
    const std::string OldFileTmpName = GenerateTempFileName( 15 );

    //# Rename the old file to a temporary name. Why? So we can rename
    // it back to its original name incase it failed to rename the
    // temporary file.
    if( std::rename( in_OldFileName.c_str(), OldFileTmpName.c_str() ) != 0 ) { 
        return 1;
    }

    //# If we successfully renamed the old file to a temporary name,
    //  we shall then attempt to rename the temporary file to the original
    //  name of the old file.

    //# Attempt to rename the temporary file. If we fail, we shall rename
    //  the old file back to its original name.
    if( std::rename( in_TempFileName.c_str(), in_OldFileName.c_str() ) != 0 ) {
        std::rename( OldFileTmpName.c_str(), in_OldFileName.c_str() );
        return -1;
    }

    //# Now if we successfully renamed the temporary file,
    //  we can go ahead and delete the old file. If failed,
    //  we shall return -2, which should only be a warning
    //  that we failed to delete the old file.
    if( std::remove( OldFileTmpName.c_str() ) != 0 ) {
        return -2;
    }

    return 0;
};


//# I wrote this function so it can instruct function ProcessFile to either skip
//  the current line (in_Line) or to output the line to the temporary file. But
//  mainly because, I did not know what your function processLine was actually
//  doing.
bool ProcessLine( std::string &in_Line ) {
    //# If in_Line is equal to "SkipThisLine", we shall return true,
    //  which means to skip the line. Else, it will return false,
    //  which simply means to no skip the line.
    return ( in_Line == "SkipThisLine" );
};

/*
 * @ FUNCTION: Example
 * @ DESCRIPTION:
 *   This function is an example of how to read and write a file and also
 *   to answer the question above.
 */
bool Example() {
    //# Attempt to open InFile (Test.txt).
    std::ifstream InFile( "Test.txt" );

    //# Return false if we are unable to open InFile.
    if( ! InFile.is_open() ) {
        std::cerr << "\nUnable to open file: Test.txt\n";
        return false;
    }

    //# Generate a unqiue name for the temporary file.
    const std::string TempFileName = GenerateTempFileName( 15 );

    //# Create temporary file.
    std::ofstream TempFile( TempFileName );

    std::string InLine = "";

    //# Begin processing each lines within InFile.
    while( std::getline( InFile, InLine ) ) {
        //# Process the line and check if we are suppose to skip it or not.
        if( ! ProcessLine( InLine ) ) {
            //# If we do not skip the line, we shall then write it to the
            //  temporary file (TempFile).
            TempFile << InLine << std::endl;
        }
    }

    //# Now that we are done with InFile, we can
    //  close both InFile and TempFile and continue
    //  to the next set of steps.
    InFile.close();
    TempFile.close();

    //# Attempt to rename the temporary file to Test.txt.
    short Error = OldFileToTempFile( "Test.txt", TempFileName );

    //# Check if there are no error or if the error is -2. 
    //  The -2 means that we successfully renamed the temporary
    //  file but we were unable to delete the old file.
    if( Error == 0 || Error == -2 ) {
        return true;
    }

    //# Failed to rename temporary file.
    return false;
};

int main() {

    if( Example() ) {
        std::cout << "Success!" << std::endl;
    } else { std::cout << "Failed!" << std::endl; }

    ::getchar();
    return 0;
};
```

Please do read the comments, they really help! :)

I've made some important changes due to @Michael Anderson's comment below, we can thank him for that.

Comment: Its important to think about what happens in the case of an exception or error, and how that could effect the output. Probably also worth using OS level functions that give you a proper temp file with unique name (Though they dont usually play so well with C++). (E.g. what happens if you have two copies of this code running at the same time - they'll stomp on each others temp files.)

Comment: Note that a real-world implementation of the "save-with-new-name-then-rename" pattern is considerably more complicated, since you want to maintain attributes, ownership, and ACLs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea using random access methods that you can work with. It leaves trailing old data at the end that depending on your application you could ignore or remove. Getting that correct would depend on if the lines are all the same size. However, this should remove the lines you want to skip.

```
char buffer[10];
fstream fs("test.txt");
std::string inputLine;
bool skipLine = false;
long nextRead, nextWrite;
int skippedLines = 0;

if (fs)
{
    while (!fs.eof())
    {


        if (!skipLine && skippedLines == 0)
            nextWrite = fs.tellg();
        getline(fs, inputLine);

        nextRead = fs.tellg();
        if (fs.eof()) break;

        cout << inputLine << endl;
        skipLine = processLine(inputLine);

        if (!skipLine) {
            fs.seekp(nextWrite);
            fs << inputLine << std::endl;

            if (skippedLines > 0) {
                nextWrite = fs.tellp();
            }

            fs.seekg(nextRead);
            if (fs.eof()) break;
        } else {
            fs.seekg(nextRead);
            skippedLines++;
        }
    }
}
```